# How compile an OpenCV program via command-line(Ubuntu)?

Tags: opencv, command-line, compiler-errors, compilation

I have an OpenCV code that I can compile and run with codeblocks successfully. But when I try it from command line by this command(that I founded on the web):

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binary  main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_stitching
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
```

It gives me:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib /usr/bin/ld: cannot find
>   -lopencv_legacy collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And when I try to delete `-lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy` from my command, it gives me:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccL2lHM7.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4: error adding symbols: DSO
>   missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Opencv 3.4.1 the paths in command are true`usr/local/include` and `usr/local/lib`.

Comment: If you're not sure which libs to add to your compilation, then do: `g++ main.cpp -o binary \`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs\``.

Comment: @zindarod: Thank you so much, it worked. But may you explain more in an answer, how does your suggestion works and how can I use it in future same conditions for other libraries? Also, what is the difference between your suggested code and what I have written in my question (with `-L` or `-I` or `-l` options).